# dropdown item does not display by background android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I have a Dropdown in my android app.but when I set background for it, dropdown item does not display.
my .xml file:

```
 <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="254dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:background="@drawable/red_color"/>
```

red_colot.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:top="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:bottom="3dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/red" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Could you please share the full drawable code?

Comment: @Sabari I shared it.

Comment: try this: red_color.xml:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="3dp" />
</shape>

Comment: No, did not solve my problem

Comment: Oh I see, I can't reproduce your bug. In my side, drawable xml, while using your code, item tag is not resolving (the item tag should not be a direct tag.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can resolve this with this code

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/green" />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="right|center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_gray" />
</item>
```